# How to check multiple cookies in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, popup, jquery-cookie

I am trying to check more than one cookie in order to have a pop-up display or not display.  What I have works only if I am checking for one cookie but not both.

```
$(window).load(function() {

  var delay = 5000; // milliseconds
  var cookie_expire = 30; // days (when to show visitor the popup again)

  //only show popup if the user doesn't have a "hide" cookie set or "Login" cookie set
  if (($.cookie('hide_popup') != "1" && window.innerWidth > "800") || ($.cookie('Login') == "null" && window.innerWidth > "800")) {
    $("#popup").delay(delay).fadeIn("fast", function() {

      $("#popup-signup").load("/popup-content.php", function() {
        $("#popup-signup").fadeIn("fast", function() {

        });
      });
    });
    //set the popup to not show again for the set period
    $.cookie('hide_popup', '1', {
      expires: cookie_expire,
      path: '/'
    });
    //close popuop function
    $("#closepopup").live("click", function() {

      //hide popup
      $("#popup, #popup-signup").hide();


      $.cookie('hide_popup', '1', {
        expires: cookie_expire,
        path: '/'
      });
    });
  }
});
```

I am trying to set a cookie and check for a cookie already being set by the login.

Comment: What outdated version of jQuery are you using that `live` is still supported? Why are you comparing a number to a string? `"800"` should not have quotes. `"null"` is not equal to `null`

Comment: It s a code I found online. I am not a JavaScript programmer I work on PHP so I understand enough to be dangerous so to speak.

Comment: Well the jQuery code is outdated since `live` has been deprecated and removed in current versions.

Answer (score 0):

When you compare numbers, you should not wrap a number in quotes.

When you compare to null, you should not wrap null in quotes.

```
if(($.cookie('hide_popup') != "1" && window.innerWidth > 800) || ($.cookie('Login') == null && window.innerWidth > 800))
 {
```

The cookie check is fine since it is a string so that `"1"` should be in quotes.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check if a cookie doesn't exists, as I think you are doing in this line:

```
if(($.cookie('hide_popup') != "1" && window.innerWidth > "800") || ($.cookie('Login') == "null" && window.innerWidth > "800"))
```

You have to do:

```
 if(($.cookie('hide_popup') != "1" && window.innerWidth > "800") || ($.cookie('Login') == null && window.innerWidth > "800"))
```

In the upper code you check if the value of the cookie is the string `"null"` and not if it is the empty value `null`.